# jquery slider image doesnt move to shift

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery slider and I want to move my image according to how slider moves but for some reason its not working for me 
here is the code

```
   .main{
        background: transparent  url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 20px 30px;;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: 322px;
        font-family: 'Futura-Book';

    }

<div id="background-image-horizontal"></div>
```

//slider

```
$('#background-image-horizontal').slider({
                max: 50,
                min: 10,
                value: 14,
                slide: function(e,ui) {
                    console.log("transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat "+ui.value+"px 1px");
                    $('.main').css("background","transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat "+ui.value+"px 1px");
                }
            });
```

In my console I see this changing when I move slider but on my screen the image doesnt move

```
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 28px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 29px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 30px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 31px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 32px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
transparent url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 33px 1px ?img=bootsImg.jpg&w=300&h=300:330
```

Comment: fixed in question...but the issue is not resolved

Comment: <?= image ?> is bootsImg.jpg...cahnge in question

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: All I did here was give your div a height (and modify the code to change just the position, which shouldn't matter): http://jsfiddle.net/jL3ju/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be that you have  no height mentioned for your `.main` and i believe it is a `div`, so it takes 0 height. try set some `height`.

```
.main{
        background: transparent  url(/img/ads/bootsImg.jpg) no-repeat 20px 30px;;
        width: 300px;
        height:200px; /*Set some height*/
        background-size: 322px;
        font-family: 'Futura-Book';

    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QfWRW/)**